# Vertically centering text in a div while having a div that is 100% width

Tags: css, border

So this might be a dupe, but I'm checking other posts, and this is slightly different.

I want to center text in a div both vertically and horizontally. I got that part working fine. My only issue is I have a div that should have a solid green thick border that fills 100% of the container with a 50% border radius.

Got all that with one remaining issue. When I switch to display to table-cell, the div's width is the width of the text. Not the width of the container. This is not what I was expecting to see. I have a CodePen on it here (https://codepen.io/databell/pen/oNjMVmj) and I'll post the code below. It's from the Elementor Page Builder, but it really could reflect any div relationship that's similar.

HTML

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-aedd1c1 core-value elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <h3 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Stack Overflow</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.elementor-widget-wrap > .elementor-element {
    width: 100%;
}
.core-value .elementor-widget-container {
    height: 320px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: #3FBE9C;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.core-value h3 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were going for?  If so what I did was made the position absolute so the circle would fill the whole container, then aligned the text with text-align: center; and line-height: 320px; (the same as your height)  Hope this helps.

```css
.elementor-widget-wrap > .elementor-element {
    width: 100%;
}
.core-value .elementor-widget-container {
    height: 320px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;  
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-color: #3FBE9C;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 320px;
    
}
.core-value h3 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-aedd1c1 core-value elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <h3 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">CodePen Help</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. I first had to add a height: 320px; to the .elementor-widget-wrap > .elementor-element.core-value class. Otherwise, the circle would have no height. Now the circle is the right height and width but the text is not vertically aligned to the middle. It's on top instead.